# some novice questions about VPS

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, mysql

I have ordered a VPS today, and I am still setting it up. I have some Q though:
Also, I have just installed apache, php and mysql.

1- I don't understand which folder my website should be in. Is it the 'www' folder or the htdocs folder I should upload my site to? Because they are in entirely different directories.

2- How do I even upload files? FTP program? How do I install one, and which one?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's your server, so it's your choice. Just make sure it's configured for whatever folder you pick.
2. You'll need a server program, if you've got SSH on there already, use SFTP. [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) is a great client for transferring files.
   Otherwise you might enable (install?) an [FTP server](https://help.ubuntu.com/6.06/ubuntu/serverguide/C/ftp-server.html). Filezilla would still work good for this. If you use FTP, make a special FTP account with a different password than everything else, and make it very very long and complex.

Comment: In 2010, there is no *good* reason to use unencrypted FTP over the Internet, but there are plenty of good reasons not to.  The security precautions mentioned above would be necessary at minimum, but it would be both easier and more secure to simply use SFTP from the outset.

Comment: scp is a nice command-line front end to sftp.